# Is Angular Js Code Visible On Browser In Mean Stack Development?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, javascript-security

Recently I read  great article about mean stack development . As in node js , script render on server side and not visible in browser . My question is that  " Is script of angular js visible on browser when we use views and controller of angular (and using mongo db, node js and express to make API)" ?

Comment: Yes, angular runs in browser , node does not. Not hard to see for yourself if you open any mean page and inspect source

Answer (score 1):

To clear your confusion. Let look at what is AngularJs and NodeJs.

NodeJs = Backend, server side. If you are from C#, Java Background, It's ASP.NET Web API, ASP.NET MVC, or Java Spring Framework.Therefore you code live in server, not visible for user.

AngularJs = Front-end Framework / library. It live in browser, just like jquery. The code you wrote will be visible on broswer.

Javacript nowadays can be used in both front-end and backend. MEAN stack is just a way to teach people how to use these technologies together.